# Regex matching except when pattern is after another pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

I am looking to find method names for python functions. I only want to find method names if they aren't after `"def "`. E.g.:

```
"def method_name(a, b):" # (should not match)
"y = method_name(1,2)"   # (should find `method_name`)
```

My current regex is `/\W(.*?)\(/`.

Comment: I understand the exclusion criterion, but I don't understand the inclusion criterion. For example, suppose the second line were `y = str[1..-1].upcase`. Would you want the method `[]=` or `upcase` returned? I suspect that the second line must have a particular form, but you have not said what that is. Is it always a variable, an equals sign, the method name (without syntactic sugar), as in your example? Please clarify by editing.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "def no_match(a, b):\ny = match(1,2)"
str.scan(/(?<!def)\s+\w+(?=\()/).map(&:strip)
#⇒ ["match"]
```

The regex comments:

- negative lookbehind for `def`,
- followed by spaces (will be stripped later),
- followed by one or more word symbols `\w`,
- followed by positive lookahead for parenthesis.

*Sidenote*: one should never use regexps to parse long strings for any purpose.

Comment: Have you tested this ? Because lookahead assertion won't be true for `(1,2)` as you are only looking forward for `()`.

Comment: @noob I don’t understand your complain. Probably because you failed to count parentheses. Go and test it yourself.

Comment: Ow ! My bad. I did failed to count it.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that lines that do not contain "def" are of the form "[something]=[zero or more spaces][method name]".

```
R1 = /
     \bdef\b   # match 'def' surrounded by word breaks
     /x        # free-spacing regex definition mode 

R2 = /
     [^=]+      # match any characters other than '='
     =          # match '='
     \s*        # match >= 0 whitespace chars
     \K         # forget everything matched so far
     [a-z_]     # match a lowercase letter or underscore
     [a-z0-9_]* # match >= 0 lowercase letters, digits or underscores
     [!?]?      # possibly match '!' or '?'
     /x         

def match?(str)
  (str !~ R1) && str[R2]
end

match?("def method_name1(a, b):") #=> false 
match?("y = method_name2(1,2)")   #=> "method_name2" 
match?("y = method_name")         #=> "method_name" 
match?("y = method_name?")        #=> "method_name?" 
match?("y = def method_name")     #=> false 
match?("y << method_name")        #=> nil
```

I chose to use two regexes to be able to deal with both my first and penultimate examples. Note that the method returns either a method name or a falsy value, but the latter may be either `false` or `nil`.